# Get android version in .csproj

Tags: c#, maui, csproj

I'm currently working on a splash screen for my app, however, Google seem to have made some changes to how it renders on Android 12+ and the splash image gets messed up. I need to have a condition in .csproj to check whether or not the Android device is running Android 12+.

I've made similar conditionals but they only take into account the OS platform and not the version of a OS.

For example:

```
<MauiIcon Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net7.0-ios'" Include="Resources\AppIcon\iosicon.svg" Color="#FFFFFF" />
<MauiIcon Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net7.0-android'" Include="Resources\AppIcon\androidicon.svg" Color="#FFFFFF" />
```

Edit: It seems there is no way of checking this, so we've decided just to use the app-icon for the splash screen. Until google revert this horrible change.

Comment: Can you describe the situation of the splash image in the Android 12 on your side?

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT Thanks for your reply! Basically what's happening is this https://github.com/dotnet/maui/pull/9797 You can't take advantage of the entire screen, google have limited the rendering area to a small circle in the middle which my splash image does not fit. My splash image contains the company name which need to take up the entire screen horizontally. Like I said, this just happens on Android 12+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Condition` of the MauiIcon only provide the method to recognize the different platform. There not contain a way to get the version of the current platform.

You can check this article about [Platform-specific configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/app-icons?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=android#platform-specific-configuration) for more information.